# Controller function is not called with ng-click when I pass data to an isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I'm trying to connect 3 components by using a general controller that joins all: countries, regions and cities. Each component is a dropdown menu with tagged data, when I select when option of the first dropmenu the second must show the data asociated with the option choosen.

The problem is that I want to make reusable components, so the array with the information comes from the general controller. If the information is inside of the component controller and I select an option ng-click calls the function defined in it and everything works fine, but if the array data comes from the scope the function is not called... I though that was a problem of references and angular was searching the function in the supercontroller but no...

What is happening? Thanks for all!

**RegionComponent JS**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('regionModule', [])
.directive('regionDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'regionController',
        scope:{
          data : '=',
          'region': '='
        },
        link: function ($scope) {
            $scope.regionHasBeenSelected = function (data) {
                $scope.region(data);
            };
        },
        templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/regionModule.html'
    };
})
.controller('regionController', function ($scope) {
    this.regionList = $scope.data;
    console.log('Region List is ' + $scope.data);

    this.selectRegion = function (id) {
        for (var x in this.regionList) {
            if (this.regionList[x].tag == id) {
                console.log(this.regionList[x].name + ' selected');
                $scope.regionHasBeenSelected(this.regionList[x].tag);
            }
        }
    };

});
```

**RegionComponent HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Region
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
  <li ng-repeat="region in data">
      <a ng-click='controller.selectRegion(region.tag)'>{{region.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a Plunkr with the code: [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Okxk2z8BKfSSQVeLud4g?p=preview)

Sorry for the errors, is the first time I create one ^^

Comment: change this  'region': '=' to  region: '='

Comment: the plunkr you created is not running at all. I presume you just created new plain plunkr, but you should create an angularjs one. Plus, keep it simple and post only relevant to the question files and code. Otherwise it is just way too confusing what you have there now.

Comment: You are right Diana, sorry for  the confusing information :(

Comment: @Juandi can you explain what is the functionality of the entire module you are trying to create, it seems a bit odd what I see in those controllers and markup files.

Comment: @DianaR I have updated the Plunkr, now works :). I need to have 3 selectors as isolated components, the first one have the information inside it's controller just to test, when I choose an option the super controller (worldController) have to give to the second controller (regions) the regions of the selected country, and the same idea for the third. The problem is when I inherit the data from worldController the function inside regionController is never called with ng-click, but if the data is natively stored inside regionController ng-click works... I don't know if i have explained well...

Comment: Ok. I understand the logic. Will take a loot at the plunkr

Comment: Do you need specificaly the directives not to be within the main scope of the controller?

Comment: Exactly, they need to be completly isolated, only with the reference of the main controller to get the selected data from the directive

Comment: @Juandi I can't see the city list defined in your plunkr.

Comment: Sorry @DianaR I deleted it from the worldModule.js when I create the plunker, now is there again

Comment: @Juandi please check this solution. There are many things I had to change. If this is what you expect, I will post as an asnwer: https://plnkr.co/edit/yL9RxrlTZtAFB70Dt4Ws?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

For passing the reference of a function you need to use '&' and not '='. '=' is for 2-way data binding and '&' is used for passing external function reference.

Comment: You are right, but here there is no reference to the funciton at all passed to the directive.

Comment: Yeah @Pratik you are right, but here I wrap the function inside link only to get out the data of the directive, is not called inside it :)